# parameterized build configuraion in jenkins with git Commit id

Tags: git, jenkins

How can I configure a parametrized build in Jenkins with git Commit id?
I have two parameters:

1. BRANCH_NAME
2. COMMIT_ID

I just want to build in Jenkins with Commit Id.... As i can Build with Tag....

Comment: Could you give some more details? At least I have *no idea* what you are planning to do...

Comment: I am using ant to build the EAR.  and using Git As as a code management tool. So we have configured with jenkins to Build a EAR. so that we can build the EAR with latest revision but not previous revision. i just want to build the ear with any commit ID........... if i tag the branch and then i have configured in jenkins its working fine....   if you need any clarification please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can parameterize your build with two string paramaters (BRANCH_NAME and COMMIT_ID).  You should enter a default for the branch, so that whatever branch you use most (hopefully master) is automatically populated.  Defining parameters is discussed in detail [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

In the branch specifier section (under branches to build) enter the following:

```
*/$BRANCH_NAME $COMMIT_ID
```

This will make it so instead of "Build" you will have "Build with Parameters".  Manually triggering the build will cause you to be prompted to enter the branch name and commit.  For the commit, you can either enter the whole hash or just the first 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

You can pass the *Commit-Id* as a parameter in the *branch specifier section*

So, the Answer would be:

```
$COMMIT_ID
```

[image]

**LONG ANSWER**

I wanted to do the same. Allow the user to specify the *Branch Name* and the *Commit Id*.
I tried the answer provide by @Forest and I was receiving the error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

On checking the Help for **Branch Specifier**, I found that it was possible to pass the *Commit Id* as a standalone parameter.

But my concern here was that if I merge two branches, which branch would it pick the commit from (Noob thought).

A commit actually exists on a single branch. Even if two branches are merged, the commit is technically part of the original branch it was committed to.
It is easy to visualise this if you see the flow graph of two merged branches.